# String comparison in WHERE not returning appropriate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Parts` which I created with `create table Parts(pid int, pname varchar(30),color varchar(30));`.

I loaded some data into it:

```
SELECT * FROM Parts;
 pid |   pname   |   color   
-----+-----------+-----------
   1 |  'thing'  |  'red'
   2 |  'thing2' |  'red'
   3 |  'thing3' |  'purple'
   4 |  'thing4' |  'green'
   5 |  'thing5' |  'green'
(5 rows)
```

I'd like to get all the rows where color is `red`, but when I try what I think is the correct query, this is the result:

```
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE color = 'red';
 pid | pname | color 
-----+-------+-------
(0 rows)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s97RFS9WXTdjgNZUoTQ1Dd/0

Comment: Maybe some spaces or special characters in that color data?

Comment: @juergend that was it. My data file had lines like `1, 'thing', 'red'` so the delimiter in the copy command I used was incorrect.

Comment: Works for me on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f7a7061d5d06251df6670a91d2037df0)

Comment: try `where trim(color) = 'red'`

Comment: Do the `color` values have quotes? Normally `psql` would display a string `'red'` as just `red` so perhaps the column values have quotes in the strings (i.e. `'''red'''` was inserted rather than `'red'`). What does the `select '-' || color || '-' from parts;` result look like?

Comment: @muistooshort yes they do; removing the quotes fixed it. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quotes in the strings. Normally `psql` would display strings without quotes do I'd expect to see output like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Parts;
 pid |   pname   |   color   
-----+-----------+-----------
   1 |  thing    |  red
   2 |  thing2   |  red
   3 |  thing3   |  purple
   4 |  thing4   |  green
   5 |  thing5   |  green
(5 rows)
```

so I'd guess that you've somehow inserted `'''red'''` rather than `'red'`.

A quick'n'dirty check would be to look at:

```
select '-' || color || '-' from parts;
```

and see what you get. That would also show you any stray whitespace (but not interesting Unicode characters).

Comment: Hello @mu-is-too-short trying to reach you. Can we connect and talk for a few?